How does Lorentz contraction take place for a cylinder moving in a direction parralel to the flat surface of cylinder?
So I know that Lorentz contraction does not occur in the transverse direction. However for a particle in a relative frame moving across the diameter of the flat surface of cylinder it should witness contraction in diameter along its relative velocity however that would imply that diameter perpendicular to this direction also contracts because the circular shape should be maintained? Or are there two possibilities: 1) There will be no longitudinal contraction in such cases. 2) The constraints of shape will not be followed in such cases i.e. the flat surface will look distorted in such a frame.

Maintaining shape is not mandatory.
